# fetching datas from two tables satisfying the where condition

Tags: mysql, select, merge

I have a doubt.can I do the following two queries in one query itself??

`SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND status<>200 ORDER BY  time_stamp ASC LIMIT 2 "`

and`SELECT email FROM table2 WHERE wid='".$xy."'"` 
where `$xy` is the id fetched from first select query.

my php code:

```
$dat =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND status<>200 ORDER BY  time_stamp ASC LIMIT 2 ");
while($dt=  mysql_fetch_assoc($dat)){
$add=  mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table2 WHERE wid='".$dt['id']."'");
$result=  mysql_fetch_assoc($add);
$to=$result['email'];
$subject="site down";
$message="your site is down";
$header="From:admin@gmail.com";
$retval=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);}
```

my tables looks like below:

table1:

```
id        url      status      time_stamp

9       dgfgg     404        2012:09:05 13:04:56

10       gfh      404        0000:00:00 00:00:00

11        fg      200        0000:00:00 00:00:00
```

table2:

```
wid    email

9       ufff@hguh

10      yfyff@hfg

11      yfyf@hg.com
```

can anybody suggest one query that do the work instead of writing two as i did in my php code??

Comment: Could you post the result of the first select?

Comment: @Mihai: its an int id 9 and 10. this same ids are there in table 2, which also contains corresponding mail ids. i need to mail to that mail ids.

Comment: SELECT email FROM table2 WHERE wid IN(9,10)  does this work?

Comment: @Mihai: yeah thats worked..but when i combine two queries it didn't worked..

Comment: @user007 Nothing to do with your error, but shouldn't $subject,$message,$header string assignments be outside the loop? No need to do them again and again.

Comment: @rakeshjain: the above php code is the one i wrote with separate queries.. its working well... my problem is in when i used the combined query that you suggested it dont work not in my mailing function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT email FROM table2 WHERE wid=(SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
AND status<>200 ORDER BY time_stamp ASC LIMIT 2)
```

Ooops,in case it returns more than one id use IN instead of =

```
$dat =mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table2 WHERE wid IN(SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
AND status<>200 ORDER BY time_stamp ASC)LIMIT 2  ");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($dat)){
$to=$result['email'];
$subject="site down";
$message="your site is down";
$header="From:admin@gmail.com";
$retval=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);}
```

Yeah,and mysql functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5,use mysqli or PDO.

EDIT ok,try to put LIMIT 2 outside the first parenthesis

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1152d/1.

Comment: this works well when only one id is taken.. but when two id is selected it both didn't works..i mean IN and = ..

Comment: i included that in my post

Comment: the edited code you posted worked well for one entry where status!=200. but when there is more than one entries with status!=200 it didn't working. [i added a line in my code for printing $to to check whether it is working]

Comment: Post the table schema and some data.Even there are more than one column <>200 it should work.

Comment: thanks it worked now when limit is put outside the paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT email FROM table2 WHERE wid IN (SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
AND status<>200 ORDER BY time_stamp ASC LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: @user007 can you show your database schema with sample data. I don't see anything wrong in this query